# Angular version upgrade issue 12 ,13,14 and 15

Tags: angular, angular14, angular15, angular16

everyone, I upgraded the angular application from version 8 to 15 or 16.
I follow the steps.
I'm using angular material and hightcharts.
steps:
1st I updated from version 8 to 9, and it's working fine.
2nd 9 to 10 are working fine.
when I came from 14 to 15 it was not working I resolved all issues during the upgrade from 14 to 15
Angular guideline
Required:
Angular 15 node version ^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || ^18.10.0
I installed 16.13.0
Gave Angular material css import issue and I fixed it application runs when click on the login application does not move to the dashboard my loader is running not give any error.
when check in network request it give me style.css status code 304.

below are the screen shots.

[image]

I fixed this error by using the below command.

@import '../../../node_modules/@angular/material/theming' ;

My screen is stuck on loading not giving any response.

[image]

Comment: First of all, import can be shortened to `@import 'node_modules/...';`. Secondly, if your app was compiled sucessfully and, as you say, your screen stuck on loading the app then there was an exception thrown and you have to provide the details about this exception.

Comment: bro I already mentioned no exception occurs

Comment: then obviously you didn't migrate your app correctly, bro

Comment: May be but I update all the packages one by one.